# JavaScript Try Catch

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some code on a website that hides / shows content on a click.

```
    function expando() {
        try {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
                var e = document.getElementsByClassName("expandlink"); 
                t = 0;
            } else {
                var e = document.querySelectorAll(".expandlink"),
                    t = 1;
            };
            if (null != e) {
                for (var a = 0; a < e.length; ++a) e[a].onclick = function() {
                    return OpenClose(this), !1
                };
                if (1 == t)
                    for (var a = 0; a < e.length; ++a) {
                        var n = e[a].href,
                            r = n.indexOf("#"),
                            i = n.substr(r + 1),
                            l = document.getElementById(i);
                        l.className = l.className + " expandtargetIE8"
                    }
            }
        } catch (o) {}
    }

    function OpenClose(e) {
        try {
            var t = e.href,
                a = t.indexOf("#"),
                n = t.substr(a + 1),
                r = document.getElementById(n);
            r.className = "expandtarget" === r.className ||
                "expandtarget expandtargetIE8" === r.className ?
                "expandtargeted" : "expandtarget expandtargetIE8",
                e.className = "expandlink" === e.className ?
                "expandlink expandlinked" : "expandlink"
        } catch (i) {}
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        expando()
    };
```

Here is the JS Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/amykirst/3hbxwv1d/

I've never seen the JavaScript try...catch statement. I looked at some tutorials, and they all say that they are for error testing. Why would it be used here?

It doesn't look like the catch actually does anything.

Note: this code had been minified. I used an online tool to unminify it.

Comment: It's a common pattern to use `catch` to recover from expected error conditions and ignore them. There are many opinions about whether using try/catch represents a good practice or not, so such a discussion is not likely to be appropriate for SO. Also, you may have already seen it in your research, but MDN is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: That doesn't look like code you should be learning any lessons from, at least lessons other than "don't write code like this".

Comment: It's not used for "error testing". It's used for "error catching". The above means, "If anything goes wrong, just continue". For instance, if `document.getElementById(n)` returns null because the element does not exist, then `r.className` will fail; the `try/catch` will intercept this. However, I do not recommend this style of programming. Among other reasons, although we do not usually worry about minor performance issues, `try/catch` is notoriously slow. Also, this style gives no warning or message about the error--just silently swallows it. It's the "lazy man's" approach to catching errors.

Comment: With your example it looks like laziness on the developers part. "I want this to work now, and not break the page if it doesn't." -- like others have pointed out, this isn't code you want to be learning from =/

Comment: An empty catch block would never pass a code review in our team, specially when the try block is gigantic. It's lazy coding, you should understand where your code could error out and actually do something about problems, not ignore them. Ignoring errors is they way to get your application in an unstable state and cause all kinds of hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `try..catch` block here *is* used for error handling. It's used here to allow the code to continue normal execution if an error does arise.

Not all browsers will support both `document.getElementsByClassName` and `document.querySelectorAll`. On a browser which doesn't support either, we'd get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: `document.querySelectorAll` is not a function

...and further code execution would stop.

However with a `try..catch` block here, the code instead wouldn't alert us about the error at all (at least, not without inspecting `o` within the `catch` block). Execution would continue as normal. It's no longer an *uncaught* error, it's a *caught* error which simply has nothing done with it.

If in the same browser we're to adjust the above code to log `o` within the `catch` block:

```
... } catch (o) { console.log(o) }
```

The same message shown above would be displayed on the console, without the "uncaught" part:

> TypeError: `document.querySelectorAll` is not a function(…)

Comment: Allowing the code to continue when an error happens without recovering from it is very likely to cause hard to find bugs. I know you're just explaining  what is going on, but a disclaimer is in order. Right now it looks like you're encouraging this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are few real use case of try-catch.

1. **Error handling :** Your JS function/statements may throw error, like TypeError (Accessing undefined,null) , JsonParseError etc. Sometimes you need that to be handled, so that next set of statements has to be executed. If it is not handled, the JS engine will throw it and halts the function execution.
2. Getting meaningfull information from **multiple function call stack**: You may get into situation, in legacy codes, that function f1 is calling f2 and f2 calling f3 and so on. You may want to do some validation check and if validation fails you may like to stop the flow and show meaningfull error message. (like saying, invalid state). To handle this kind of scenario, we can handle with **Custom Exception.**

   ```
   function ValidationError(message) {
       this.name = "IocError";
       this.message = (message || "Validation/System Error");
   }
   ValidationError.prototype = Error.prototype;
   ```

   we can throw the custom error, if we see any validation error, like `throw new ValidationError('Rule is missing...')` in the function f3.

   ```
   try {
      ...
   } catch(e) {
       if(e instanceof ValidationError) {
           infoBox(e.message);
           return false;
       } else {
           //This is not validation error, some other unknown issue has occurred
           throw e;
       }
   }
   ```

   We will use the above block to catch the exception in function f1 and if it is of type ValidationError, we'll display proper error message. If it as any other type we'll throw back for future debug purpose.